# How to make the message composition textarea expandable in Patreon?

Tags: patreon

I've been having a terrible time having conversations with people I support on Patreon. Their messaging system is just horrible with perhaps the textboxes being the most glaring problem since you can't have reasonable conversations with folks who are longer winded.

Example: 
[image: patreon example]

I've looked into Chrome extensions that resize the textareas as well as [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) [scripts](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts?q=textarea), but nothing has worked out so far.

Has anyone found a way to make these textareas more friendly to writing larger messages via (at least) expansion / resize?

Comment: @Alex, curious, why'd you feel the need to modify my title such that it no longer would say `Patreon messaging sucks: how How to make the message composition textarea expandable in Patreon?`

Comment: Two reasons: (1) it doesn’t add any useful information to the question; and (2) it might get the question deleted.

Comment: @Alex thanks for clarifying. Surprising since I've seen that opinionated (especially when correct) titles get more views on questions I've seen. I guess it would be nice if there was a clarification as to why edits were made vs just making them. Too often junk edits come into the picture for point mongering on SE network...